# Edit custom list item using workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hi I have created two custom lists,L1 and L2 with same columns, listed below.

```
Title(Single line of text)
Name(Single line of text)
```

I've written a workflow that copies the newly created item from L1 to L2 using "copy list item" action of workflow. Now I want to update the respective item in L2 when item is updated in L1 using the workflow. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make this workflow run not only on item creation, but also on item update and modify item on the second list accordingly. If you have problems with this, please describe the issue in more details. Another thing is that I'm not sure if you considered using an event receiver instead of workflow. I suppose it's capable of this and may be more appropriate for this task.

Comment: Like Lucas said, use an Event Receiver, I guess is way better to do this magic trick...

Comment: @Lucas: I have been told that Custom Code is not allowed. I ran the workflow on item update but it creates new item in List2. Could you please let me know how can I modify item in second list accordingly becasue I am not able to find respective action for that. Thanks a ton.

Comment: My reply is quite long for a comment, so I posted it as an answer. Let me know if this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do it using Sharepoint designer without writing any code?

If so, I suppose you can try to use variables to identify item in the other list, as described in ***Add conditions to the workflow*** section here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/use-variables-in-workflows-HA010240415.aspx#BM1.

You can also find some explanation of a similar issue here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/99f623f1-ef1b-42bf-abbe-4f4b2e7b2ded and some info on updating item here: http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/workflow/use-update-list-item-action-sharepoint-designer-workflow.htm.